# Parsing variable and segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am having an issue with getting a user string passed in as a variable parsed in order to store each seperate word in it's own variable. Below is my attempt at this.

There is another part of the program in `client.c` that is requesting user input. Once I type in a string in the client "foo 123 anwhere blah" it gets passed into the server program below as the variable `buf`. Once I have it I make a copy of it into `temp`, so I don't damage the original string (at least at this point in testing). Then I run the `strctok` against the variable trying to parse out each word.

If I'm even on the right track at the moment it will compile with no errors and run. However when I send data to it from the client a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" appears.

Can anyone shed any light as to why?

```
        /*
 * server.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define SERVER_PORT 1617 
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

struct sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t addrlen;
char buf[MAX_LINE];
int len;
int s;
int new_s;
char *temp;
char fname[32], lname[32], city[32], zip[32], country[32];

/* build address data structure */
bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons (SERVER_PORT);

/* setup passive open */
if (( s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

if ((bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

listen (s, MAX_PENDING);

addrlen = sizeof(sin);
cout << "The server is up, waiting for connection" << endl;

/* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
while (1) {
    if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &addrlen)) < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "new connection from " << inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr) << endl;

    while (len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) {

        temp = buf;
        strcpy(fname, strtok(buf , " "));
            strcpy(lname, strtok(NULL, " "));
            strcpy(city , strtok(NULL, " "));
            strcpy(zip , strtok(NULL, " "));
            strcpy(country, strtok(NULL, " "));


            printf("%s\n", fname);
            printf("%s\n", lname);
            printf("%s\n", city);
            printf("%s\n", zip);
            printf("%s\n", country);


        /* send (new_s, temp, strlen(temp) + 1, 0); */
    }

    close(new_s);
}
}
```

As requested the -g option on gcc:

```
server.c:6:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory

server.c:13:19: error: cstring: No such file or directory

server.c:14:19: error: cstdlib: No such file or directory

server.c:16: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before ânamespaceâ

server.c: In function âmainâ:

server.c:42: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âexitâ

server.c:47: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âexitâ

server.c:53: error: âcoutâ undeclared (first use in this function)

server.c:53: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

server.c:53: error: for each function it appears in.)

server.c:53: error: âendlâ undeclared (first use in this function)

server.c:59: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âexitâ

server.c:65: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âmemcpyâ

server.c:66: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âstrcpyâ

server.c:66: warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcpyâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

server.c:66: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âintâ

server.c:67: warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcpyâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

server.c:67: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âintâ

server.c:68: warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcpyâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

server.c:68: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âintâ

server.c:69: warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcpyâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

server.c:69: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âintâ

server.c:70: warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcpyâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

server.c:70: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âintâ
```

Comment: Remove the C++ tag.  You're parsing 5 words from the string but your example input only has 4.

Comment: Why did you include `iostream` in an otherwise C program?

Comment: Because i'm not actually sure what language the program is in, i've used some C and some C++, or I was told I could use C++ to manipulate the strings and then return them to C

Comment: `I could use C++ to manipulate the strings and then return them to C` I suggest you do!

Comment: @Neil Kirk

Any pointers along that line would be appreciated, I have been working on this all week, and all of today and i'm not making any progress :(

Comment: "i'm not actually sure what language the program is". That's the first thing you need to decide when you start writing a program. There is no point whatsoever in discussing it before you pick a language.

Comment: The code is definitely not C code, as you try to use `iostream` and stuff like that. I removed the C tag for you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace strcpy with strncpy. and use the right length in strncpy depending the length of buffer you are copying in.
Also you are not checking the return value of strtok. As strtok can return NULL, then you are trying to do something like strcpy(str, null).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of potential issues here. First,

```
temp=buf
```

doesn't copy buf into temp, it just copies the pointer. After this line `temp` just points to the same location as `buf`. You'd need to allocate memory for temp and do a `memcpy` or similar operation.

Second, you need to check the value of `len`. There is no guarantee that `recv` received as much data as you might expect. Which means you might have to do multiple `recv` calls to get your full string.

It would be helpful to other reviewers if you could post a stack trace of your core file. At least that would point to the offending line.

Comment: I am not sure what a "stack trace of core files" are... or how to get them, or I would be more than happy to post them :)

I changed to a memcpy

Comment: @ff210327 You can get a stack trace from opening the core file with a debugger like gdb. The stack trace will show the full call stack up to the line that caused the segmentation fault. Be sure to compile with debug information in order to get this to work (-g flag in gcc). I suggest reading up on debuggers as they will be your friend.

Comment: @ff210327 Sorry, I should have been more clear. gcc -g adds extra information to the executable file created. Debuggers can then use this information to give you better information when debugging a running process or core file. What you posted was a bunch of warnings the compiler detected when it was parsing the code. It's a good practice to fix these warnings as they can often point to larger problems in your code.